# Avoiding collision when generating unique ids concurrently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, stripe-payments

I have a webhook to receive Stripe events and create new invoices accordingly.
Due to local legislation, I have to generate invoice numbers myself and cannot use Stripe ids. Those are sequential, unique ids.

I just encountered a concurrency issue as I received 2 "new draft invoice" events from Stripe at the same time.
Both events generated the same invoice number, but naturally the second could not be inserted in the PostgreSQL database and Stripe retried later.

Invoice numbers basically look like this: YYYY-XXXXX, where YYYY is the year, and XXXXX is a sequential number, starting at 00001 for the first invoice generated of the year. If the last number was 2020-00017, the next one can't be anything else but 2020-00018.

So it kind of works but doesn't seem ideal.
Do you know any better solution than letting Stripe retry?

Comment: Are you allowed to generate your UUID's from Stripe's ID? If you perform some calculation on it you can mask the original ID and still ensure unique results

Comment: Nope, it has to be sequential so it depends entirely on the IDs that were previously generated on my server. If the last one was 2020-00017 the next one has to be 2020-00018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options exist to fulfill this requirement.

As @jjanes mentioned you could return an HTTP status code >2XX status code which will cause Stripe to retry the request. This is fine if you expect few duplicates, but if you expect to scale quickly and frequently respond with >200 error codes, I would build the retry and serial processing logic into your backend.

For instance, you could push the event data onto a queue, then immediately respond with a 200 status code. Then process the events sequentially off of the queue in a background job. This would allow you to write your own logic for deduplicating the ID's, ensuring they are sequential, and avoiding the risk that your Webhook Endpoint on Stripe is disabled (for responding with too many  >200 status code responses).

Comment: The only issue is that I'm handling background jobs with Sidekiq which is not suited for sequential jobs. It would, however, reduce the delay between retries, and avoid any issue with Stripe as you said.

Comment: Yeah if it doesn't come out of the box, you may need to build the sequential processing on-top of sidekiq.

Answer (score 1):

I think just letting Stripe retry might be your best bet, since it has already been implemented and tested.  If someone draws the next number, there is no way to know if they are going to commit or not until they have actually done so.  So you either need to fail and retry, or block and wait, or take the next number and allow gaps if the earlier one failed.  Is there a problem with the retry, or do you just find it untidy? If there is a problem, what is it? It is hard to design a new solution without knowing what the problem is with the old one.

Comment: The problem is just my lack of experience regarding these types of issues. It works, but maybe I missed an opportunity to tidy things up just because I don't know better.